# How do I resolve conflicts between these two namespaces?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-files

In my code I'm using both these two namespaces and all works fine until I try to use the CopyStatus that exists in both.  This piece of code works just fine in LINQPad5 with the exact same namespaces, however in VS2019 I'm finding that it cannot fine CopyState in the Storage.File class.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
```

Code from LINQPad5

```
CloudFile file = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference(myfile);

string blobSas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24)
});
Uri blobSasUri = new Uri(blob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + blobSas);
file.StartCopy(blobSasUri);
file.FetchAttributes();

int count=0;
while (file.CopyState.Status != Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CopyStatus.Success)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(@"{0} - Sleep one second", count++.ToString());
    file.FetchAttributes();
}
```

But this (almost) same code does not work in VS2109.

[image]

```
file.StartCopy(bpe.BlobUri);
file.FetchAttributes();
while (file.CopyState.Status != Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CopyStatus.Success)
```

Picture showing Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.**CopyStatus** does not 
exist.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue could be mainly caused by a missing nugget from VS 2019, I'd recommend installing the latest WindowsAzure.storage Nugget found [**here**](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=windowsazureofficial)
Restart VS then retry again.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response.  I removed WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3 and then attempted to add it back, timed out multiple times when trying to install via the console.  So I restarted everything and added back in via the option "Manage NuGet for Solution" which installed the library and added a reference back in.   However the .Strorage.File. has no CopyStatus class.  I've added a screenshot into the original post above as I cannot see how to add a picture in a comment.

Comment: Not sure if this is  relevant or not, but I started this solution under VS2019 preview and then upgraded yesterday to VS2019 Enterprise.

Comment: I created a new console application and downloaded the .WindowsAzure.Storage libary, this automatically added a reference to this ..\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.9.3.3\lib\net45\Microsoft.WindowsAzure. 
 **Storage.dll** even though my solution is framework v4.6.1.   When I look at the library that LINQPad5 uses it's different ..\AppData\Local\LINQPad\NuGet.FW46\Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement\Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File.9.4.2\lib\net452\Microsoft.Azure. **Storage.File.dll**.  So LP5 uses a specific .File.dll and VS is using just .Storage and the versions are different.

Comment: that's interesting! This could be a possible bug, I'd highly recommend opening an issue in VS 2019 github repo: https://github.com/github/visualstudio/issues , it might get some traction from the VS team.

Comment: Hi, if I browse the .dll in dotPeek I can see there's no class/folder for CopyStatus.  Yes I will open an issue as you suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to upgrade to .NET framework 4.7.2 and install Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement instead of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage in NuGet.

Then qualifying the using statements:

```
using AF=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
using AB=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```